# how to derive this property of exponential distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, expected-value, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ be a real random variable with exponential distribution on a measure space with probability measure $\Bbb P$. Let $\Bbb E$ be the expected value. Then
\begin{equation}\Bbb P(X>s+t|X>s)=\Bbb P(X>t).\end{equation}

How can we derive the following property?
\begin{equation}\Bbb E(X-t|X>t) = \Bbb E(X).\end{equation}

Comment: Is $X$ discrete or continuous?

Comment: the exponential distribution is continuous

Comment: Of course lol. Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48496/conditional-expectation-of-exponential-random-variable

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_X$ be the density function of $X$. We have (by memorylessness) for all real $x,a$ \begin{equation}\Bbb P(X>x\mid X>a)=\Bbb P(X>x-a).\end{equation}

Thus, by the [Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem), $f_{X\mid X>a}(x)=f_X(x-a)$ for all $a$ and Lebesgue almost all $x$. It follows that (taken from the first answer on [Conditional expectation of exponential random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48496/conditional-expectation-of-exponential-random-variable) by [Dilip Sarwate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/6633/dilip-sarwate))

\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\Bbb E(X\mid X > x) &:= \int_{-\infty}^\infty t f_{X \mid X > x}(t)\,\mathrm dt\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty t f_X(t-x)\,\mathrm dt\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty (x+u) f_X(u)\,\mathrm du
\quad{\text{on substituting}~u = t-x}\\
&= x + E(X).
\end{split}\end{equation}

This is equivalent to your claim by linearity of the expected value.

Comment: can you explain how the conditional pdf of X given that {X>x} is the same as that of X but shifted to the right by x, please?

Comment: See for instance https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Further_details

Comment: @arashmoradi since they have the same cumulative function, they have the same PDF (almost everywhere) by the [Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem)

Comment: thanks a lot, can you explain little more or suggest the link for more study about it please

Comment: What is still unclear to you?

Comment: my first question "the conditional pdf of X given that {X>x} is the same as that of X but shifted to the right by x,"

Comment: Look at the definition of the CDF and then look at the first paragraph in the Wikipedia article on the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem.